# Extending the Mean Value Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for a More General Path

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:A\subset\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$, differentiable in the open $A$. If $A$ contains the line segment from $a$ to $a+h$ then there is a $c=a+t_0h$ with $0<t_0<1$ of this segment such that $$f(a+h)-f(a)=Df(c)\cdot h.$$

I was asked to extend this result to a path that is not necesssarily a line segment. But I don't think I'm sure what was meant by "extend".

Surely I could suppose we have a differentiable path $r:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^m$ from $a$ to $a+h$, but the expression would be $f(a+h)-f(a)=Df(r(t_0))\cdot Dr(t_0)$, which does not seem as interesting as the original, for we don't have, on the right member, the derivative of the $f$ multiplied by the length of the path taken between $a$ and $a+h$.

There is another "better" way to extend it that I do not see?

Thanks in advance.